# Connection error with SQL Server 2012 with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, linux

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 using Python 3.7 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS like this:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:192.168.0.7, 1433'
database = 'teste'
username = 'teste'
password = 'teste'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
```

When trying to connect I get the error message:

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+
> password) pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001]
> [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider:
> [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported
> protocol] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I read a [topic on git](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1056) about and tested a downgrade on openssl but it didn't solve my problem.

I have 2 versions of SQL
[Version SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LW0Q.png)

I noticed now that: In version 11.0.2100.60 I have the error that I described at the beginning. In version 11.0.6020.0, I noticed that I get a different error:

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+'
> ;PWD=' + password+';Encrypt' + encrypt) pyodbc.OperationalError:
> ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')